# Eclipse CDT toolchain clean error in windows (wrong path seperator)

Tags: eclipse, android-ndk, makefile, eclipse-cdt

I've installed eclipse + CDT for windows, loaded my project, everything builds fine.

Now I want to clean the project and rebuild my project, but it looks like eclipse (or the toolchain) is doing it all wrong.
The command it's trying to invoke is:

```
del  ./myClass.o  ./myClass.d  ../../MyProject
```

With this error:

```
Parameter format not correct - "myClass.o".
```

This is because `del` is a windows command and parameters are passed with `/` in windows.

So, how can i change the toolchain/eclipse to use a windows `\` path delimiter or just fix that some other way?

I just want to be able to clean the project.

My toolchain is `Android arm-linux-androideabi-4.8`
Eclipse Mars.1 (4.5.1) with CDT 8.8.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there's an attribute in the .cproject file xml the controls the clean command.

Look for the configuration tag, and set the `cleanCommand` attribute to what you want. I've set it to `rm -rf` and used gnuutils to support the command on windows.

```
<configuration artifactExtension="so" artifactName="MyProject" ... cleanCommand="rm -rf" ...>
```